# Python pandas: dynamic concatenation from get_dummies

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

having the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

cars = ["BMV", "Mercedes", "Audi"]
customer = ["Juan", "Pepe", "Luis"]
price = [100, 200, 300]
year = [2022, 2021, 2020]


df_raw = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(cars, customer, price, year)),\
                      columns=["cars", "customer", "price", 'year'])
```

I need to do one-hot encoding from the categorical variables `cars` and `customer`, for this I use the get_dummies method for these two columns.

```
numerical = ["price", "year"]
df_final = pd.concat([df_raw[numerical], pd.get_dummies(df_raw.cars),\
                      pd.get_dummies(df_raw.customer)], axis=1)
```

Is there a way to generate these dummies in a dynamic way, like putting them in a list and loop through them with a for.In this case it may seem simple because I only have 2, but if I had 30 or 60 attributes, would I have to go one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `pd.get_dummies`

```
pd.get_dummies(df_raw, columns=['cars', 'customer'])
```

---

```
   price  year  cars_Audi  cars_BMV  cars_Mercedes  customer_Juan  customer_Luis  customer_Pepe
0    100  2022          0         1              0              1              0              0
1    200  2021          0         0              1              0              0              1
2    300  2020          1         0              0              0              1              0
```

Comment: you made it so simple, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to concatenate the columns and use [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
cols = ['cars', 'customer']
out = df_raw.join(df_raw[cols].agg('|'.join, axis=1).str.get_dummies())
```

output:

```
       cars customer  price  year  Audi  BMV  Juan  Luis  Mercedes  Pepe
0       BMV     Juan    100  2022     0    1     1     0         0     0
1  Mercedes     Pepe    200  2021     0    0     0     0         1     1
2      Audi     Luis    300  2020     1    0     0     1         0     0
```

Another option is to [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) and use [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df2 = df_raw[cols].reset_index().melt('index')
out = df_raw.join(pd.crosstab(df2['index'], df2['value']))
```

Comment: many thanks for your solution, 
your answer being correct, I can only validate one and the other seems simpler to me. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Enrique of course that was a dummy (pun intended) oversight from my side, `pd.get_dummies` should be used directly ;)